# How to handle a GET request in python

Tags: python, flask

I have some microservices running in kubernetes, and they need to pass some data among each other, but I can't handle the GET request from the server side.

The docs I found are very focused on how to make the GET request on python, but not how to handle it.

So, this is what I tried:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<trace_id>')
def root():
    return trace_id

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

From the client, I do the request like this:

```
>>> trace_id = '54b012b2767e7b21321ca649872913c5'
>>> requests.get('http://my-service', params=trace_id)
<Response [404]>
```

And on my server I get this dumped:

```
/# python3 app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 ...
10.52.2.29 - - [29/Nov/2019 18:41:23] "GET /?54b012b2767e7b21321ca649872913c5 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I would like to know how to handle the request on the server side. Also, it would be nice to get some suggestions of what's the best way of dealing with this.

> Note: there is a k8s service in front of the server that gets the
>   requests on port 80 and forward them to 8080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `trace_id` as input argument

```
def root(trace_id):
    return trace_id
```

And trace_id is part of the url, not the query part:

```
requests.get('http://my-service/' + trace_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to look closer at your code.

```
@app.route('/<trace_id>')
```

String argument inside brackets is a path part after 'http://my_service/'.

Full path of this API endpoint will be 'http://my_service/value_of_trace_id'.

And this part 'value_of_trace_id' will be stored as 'trace_id' variable and passed to function body so you have to pass it as function (API endpoint) arg.

```
@app.route('/<trace_id>')
def api_endpoint(trace_id):
    return trace_id
```

So, you have to use:

```
requests.get('http://my-service/' + trace_id)
```

I highly recommend read [that](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html) or [that](https://hackersandslackers.com/the-art-of-building-flask-routes/).